# C++ reusing same variable name in .h file in function (this.variable = variable error?)

Tags: c++, function, this

I have a name of a variable in my .h file which a function has the same name...
for example:

```
//computer.h  
class Computer{  
private:  
    string computerName;  
    int cores;  
}  

//computer.cpp  
Computer::Computer(string computerName, int cores)  
{  
    ...  
}
```

I want to assign the values from the .cpp function to the .h file variables.

whenever i do this, it doesn't work. Am I doing it correctly??

```
this.computerName = computerName;  
this.cores=cores;
```

Comment: no problem. `:)` In future, just remember that `<code>` (as the backticks) is to insert small pieces of code inline, while the four spaces (`{}` button or Ctrl+K) is for code blocks.

Comment: By the way, at least in headers you should avoid relying on `using namespace std;`: since they may be included in files where `using namespace std;` can cause problems (name conflicts), you should always use the full names for the types in headers (`std::string`, `std::ostream`, ...).

Comment: why would you like to reuse the variable names? why not use `aComputerName` and `numCores`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of assignment, use initialization

```
Computer::Computer(string computerName, int cores) 
  :computerName(computerName), cores(cores) 
{  
    ...  
}
```

Yes that works. Constructor initializer lists have that exact purpose.

Comment: that purpose among others ... ;)

Comment: @nikeunltd, thanks for accepting. However you might want to accept @Tomalak's answer, since it's better explained and he joined SO today.

Comment: I know it is technically allowed, but I hate to see this in real code. It makes reading hard especially for beginners as it looks like self assignemnt. It is much more preferable to have slightly different names for the parameters. But that is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @Martin I don't do this in my own code either for most classes. I follow `mFoo` for members and `foo` for parameters. However when i'm doing small aggregates (like `pair`), I name members and parameters like `foo`, and use that style of initialization. I prefer that over giving parameters different names.

Comment: Personally to make it (a bit) less confusing I usually write the first letter lowercase for the field name and uppercase for the parameter name.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, `this` is a pointer, so it would be:

```
this->computerName = computerName;
this->cores = cores;
```

Comment: Because that's how the language was designed.

Comment: @nikeunltd: why is what? that this is a pointer? What else could it be? That you have to use '->' to dereference a pointer? because . means that you dereference fields of a struct or union.

Comment: @nikeunItd, @Matrin: If the question is why is `this` a pointer rather than a reference, the answer is that references came into C++ later than `this`

Answer (score 5):

If you'd posted the actual error message rather than just saying "it doesn't work", it would become clear that the issue has nothing to do with the variable names!

`this` is a pointer, so you should use the `->` operator, not `.`.

```
this->computerName = computerName;
this->cores = cores;
```

Additionally, it's advisable to accept strings by reference-to-const rather than by value, and you should really prefer initialisation over assignment; you'll find later on that for some things (notably, constants) you actually *have* to do this:

```
class Computer {
private:
    std::string computerName;
    int cores;
}

Computer::Computer(const std::string& computerName, int cores)
   : computerName(computerName)
   , cores(cores)
{}
```

Answer (score -2):

you are declaring the same variable twice.

just change it to `Computer::Computer(string computerName, unsigned int numCores)`, and instead of uusing and int, I would use an unsigned int.

in C++, this->cores ==  cores

Comment: You *can* have `computerName` both as a parameter and as a field, since they are in different scopes. The parameter will just "hide" the field, which will be still accessible via the `this` pointer.

Comment: why can't they have negative cores?

Comment: what will be the meaning of negative cores? a dumb computer will have zero cores. a useful computer will have more than zero cores.

Comment: why do you want the same name of your ivars and methods arguments? That just a confusion waiting to happen. Computer::Computer(std::string aComputerName, unsigned int numCores). do not complicate yourself.